# Can you plant potted tulips and hycinths in the ground in april

Tags: planting-times

I can't find the answer to this on Google.

Comment: Where in the world are you

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Depends on location. For example,, tulips will not rebloom in zone 8 because it is too warm.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on the weather where you are in April, and the stage of life of the bulbs in the pots. If the bulbs have grown and are either blooming or have bloomed or will bloom soon, the weather had better be pretty solidly not going to freeze or frost when you are going to plant them out (after some time of hardening them off, for better chance of success.)

If the bulbs are in pots but more or less dormant still, they might tolerate being planted out to await suitable outdoor weather for their taste to start growing in.